# Null Pointer Exception JSF

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, mojarra

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception when using my web app.
This exception is thrown at the login page. I enter both username and pass but it seems that the value or the evaluation of the expression `#{userBean.user}` or `#{userBean.pass}` is returning null.

My configuration: Apache Tomcat 7.0.22, Mojarra 2.1.6, RichFaces 4.1

Here's the stacktrace

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mx.gob.sagarpa.utilidades.Database.checkUser(Database.java:61)
    at mx.gob.sagarpa.beans.UserBean.doLogin(UserBean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 24 more
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to head to the bottomost "Caused by" part of the stacktrace for the *real* root cause. In your particular case that is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mx.gob.sagarpa.utilidades.Database.checkUser(Database.java:61)
```

You see, at line 61 of `Database` class, inside the `checkUser()` method, some object reference is `null` while the code is accessing it by the period operator `.`.

```
someObject = null;
someObject.doSomething(); // NullPointerException!
```

To fix it, you'd need to either add a nullcheck

```
if (someObject != null) {
    someObject.doSomething();
} else {
    // Take alternate path?
}
```

or to make sure that it's never `null`

```
someObject = createItSomehow();
someObject.doSomething(); // Okay.
```

Which path to take depends on the concrete functional requirement which is not clear from the question. But you should now at least understand why a `NullPointerException` can occur. This is also explained in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) (which should be the #1 source for finding information about classes, including exceptions):

> Thrown when an application attempts to use `null` in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a `null` object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a `null` object.
> - Taking the length of `null` as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of `null` as if it were an array.
> - Throwing `null` as if it were a `Throwable` value.
>
> Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the `null` object.

That said, this problem is not exactly related to JSF. It's just basic Java. I'd suggest to take some time to go through a decent basic Java book/tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I forgot to check everything. Indeed I freaked out because it was working a few hours ago but I think is related to the DB.